# Is websocket a good way to implement communication between two shiny apps?

Tags: r, shiny, websocket, ipc

I developped a shiny app that serves as a front-end for a data-base application. The app is run by Shiny Server with NGINX for authentication and HTTPS.  Once a while, I need to do some administration tasks such as changing or updating tables in the database. To do these management tasks, I intend to develop another shiny app that should be able to stop the first app and/or block access to the database to the first app while I make these changes.

I prefer to have two separate apps rather than extending the database app to include administrative functions even if it were possible to hide these functions to normal users. I intend to use the same shiny server to serve both apps.

My question is what is the best approach for the admin app to communicate with the database app. In particular, I wonder if using websocket in the following manner is a good idea:

1. Use httpuv package to start a websocket server in the global environment of the database app.
2. Use websocket package as websocket client to send message from the admin app.
3. Have the websocket server wait for message from the admin app to stop the app by using stopApp() and/or temporarily blocking access to the database by using poolClose() for example.

- I am new to web technologies and I am not sure if it is a good use case of websocket ?
- I out that websocket is not maintained on CRAN anymore. Does it mean that there is something better to be used?  *This was a mistake due to a confusion between [websocket](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/websocket/index.html) and [websockets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/websockets/index.html). The latter one was a websocket server that is replaced by [httpuv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httpuv/index.html). (Thank you to @r2evans)*
- Are there alternative approaches that are perhaps more light-weight?

Comment: I believe the industry best-practice here is to write an R package that centralizes your database-access needs and use that package by both apps. To address your question, though, realize that one app will never be truly assured that the other shiny app is active, nor if there is only one such app instance/process (depending on the shiny server options).

Comment: While I don't think it's a good way to go for this use-case ... what makes you think that the [`websocket`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/websocket/index.html) package is no longer maintained? It's still present on CRAN, and many of the package authors are generally fairly forthright with package-deprecation.

Comment: Thanks about the clarification about [websocket](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/websocket/index.html); I was confused with [websockets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/websockets/index.html).

Comment: About the first comment, my app is already divided into two packages: one dealing with application logic and database access and the other one with the front end (shiny). 

Would having a centralized database-access package require that the access be configured as a web service allowing to fetch/update data in the database?   Can you point toward an example about how to centralize data-base access for two apps?

Comment: There's really no centralization of database access, it's just about re-using code by sharing the same package(s). Just a package, nothing specifically web-oriented about its functions, you should likely be able to call them interactively on the console as well.

Comment: I agree that the issue is not necessarily web-oriented but I am not sure to understand how just sharing code would allow one app to block access to the database for the other app since the two apps would run in different R sessions.  Does it not require some form of interprocess communication or that the database access be controlled by some sort of gateway that runs independentely? I should probably ask another question to pursue this argument and I am still interested in the original question about possible better alternative to websocket for this purpose.

Comment: Why do you need to block access? The database should support multiple access.

Comment: It does support multiple access.  The reason to block is to insure consistency between the tables. Some tables are used to configure the app for a specific context or to define a set of possible values for fields that are used in other tables.

Comment: I think I understand better, but wouldn't it be better to address that in SQL? I'd think transactions could be used there, so that once all changes are made, they can be `COMMIT`ted in one fell-swoop. Another option: have a mutex somewhere that indicates the data can be queried or that it is in "maintenance mode". This can be a special-purpose table in the database (which would need to be queried each time the database-app needs data), or it could be elsewhere such as a local Redis/RabbitMQ/... instance.